# How to write value from a dataframe column to another column based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a bad time here trying to figure out how to set a column based on a condition. Basically, I want to copy the value from my "Customer" column to the rows of my "Call Ref" column, if the row is different from "Enterprise" and "Client".

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np

df_OCB['Call Ref'] = np.select([
    np.logical_and(
        df_OCB['Call Ref'] != 'Enterprise', 
        df_OCB['Call Ref'] != 'Client'
    )], 
    df_OCB['Costomer'],
    default=''
)
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `np.where()`?

`df_OCB['Call Ref'] = np.where((df_OCB['Call Ref'] != 'Enterprise') & (df_OCB['Call Ref'] != 'Client'), df_OCB['Customer'],'')`

Answer (score 0):

Not shure if this is what you really want to do because you didn't provide an example of your input and output data frames but as far as I understand it I made a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df = pd.DataFrame([['A','Enterprise'],
                   ['B','Client'],
                   ['C','Client'],
                   ['D','Something else'],
                   ['E','Enterprise']], columns=['Client','Call Ref'])

Output:

  Client    Call Ref
0   A     Enterprise
1   B     Client
2   C     Client
3   D     Something else
4   E     Enterprise
```

Here you apply a the boolean mask: `(df['Call Ref'] != 'Enterprise') & (df['Call Ref'] != 'Client')`

like this:

```
df['Call Ref'][(df['Call Ref'] != 'Enterprise') & (df['Call Ref'] != 'Client')] = df['Client'][(df['Call Ref'] != 'Enterprise') & (df['Call Ref'] != 'Client')]

Output:

    Client  Call Ref
0    A     Enterprise
1    B     Client
2    C     Client
3    D     D
4    E     Enterprise
```

If you provide more information about the Output dataframe that you want, I can give you a more concise example, hope it helped.